# Replacing an apartment interphone (2 wires)

Tags: electrical, doorbell

I live in an apartment and my intercom died. I can't find the brand of the current one, but it's probably decades old. It transmit voices from the street + a button to open the door.

I dismounted the front and noticed a 8-wire cables coming in, **but only 2 wires were used**:

[image]

I followed the cable to the hallway, opened the box where the cable goes and the result is horrendous:

[image]

There's only 2 apartments at this floor (last one), and there seems to be way too many cables.

- **I just want to replace my intercom, so I have to find a replacement
  that uses these 2 or 8 wires. What should I do?**

This also implies to additional battery/power supply.

Comment: Do you own this apartment or do you rent? If you own, may want to check with the other apartment owners to see what they have done, if anything, to repair/replace their intercom units. If you rent, this is a job for the landlord.

Comment: The building maintenance should have all the information you need for replacement.

Comment: That's not horrendous. The fact that **you think it is** means you should probably leave it alone so you don't manage to break something. Building management/maintenance will know what the deal with the intercoms is.

Comment: You shouldn't  mess with that. The fact that you're baffled  by it  means you're not familar with that type of installation. If you don't know what you're doing, you could disable/destroy the entire system  and get stuck paying for a new one.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. There is no building maintenance, it is not a thing in my country, except for really big buildings. A bunch of cable is always horrendous when they have no meaning, so I'd be happy to be oriented toward either documentation explaining how this works, or how I can use the 8 wires at my disposition to handle it

Comment: What is the outside panel like? For many apartment intercoms, the external person (visitor) presses a button for the (hopefully right) apartment, says "Hi, I'm here", and the button to open the door gets pushed. So, that mass of wiring is for all the apartments to be separately addressed. At one point someone likely had a list of which number on the big wire connection went to which apartment...

Comment: I used building maintenance as a generic term.  You can also say building owner or landlord.  One of them put in/bought the intercom system.  Someone is responsible for the building upkeep/repairs/taking your money.